# CSS: Position a symbol inside div. Can't remove space, position in the upper right corner

Tags: html, css

I have several nested divs, the last div includes a cross symbol which is supposed to be in the upper right corner. However, it's horizontally centred inside its div and has margins: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYEEjg

**html**:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="user">
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="username">some username
            <div class='cross'>
                <span class='cross-symbol'>
                    &times;              
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.content  {
    align: center;
    width: 660px;

    background-color: #c2f0c2;
    border: 2px solid black;    
}

.user  {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px; 

    background-color: gray;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;

    display: inline-block;

}

.headline {
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid black;

    position: relative;
}

.username  {
    background-color: orange;
}

.cross  { 
    font-size: 28px; 
    color: #d00; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-family: helvetica,arial;       

    cursor: pointer;

    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 28px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px;

    position: absolute; 

} 

.cross-symbol  {

    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: green;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[image]

I tried setting `padding` and `margin` to 0, but with little result. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: it should be in the upper right corner of which div? The green one or the orange one?

Comment: @fcalderan The orange one (and thus simulatenously of the small bordered one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to `.cross-symbol` and I added `line-height`

```css
.content  {
 align: center;
 width: 660px;

 background-color: #c2f0c2;
 border: 2px solid black;

 
}

.user  {
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px; 

 background-color: gray;
 margin: 8px;
 border: 1px solid gray;

 display: inline-block;
 
}

.headline {
 background-color: silver;
 border: 1px solid black;

 position: relative;
}

.username  {
 background-color: orange;
}


.cross  { 
 font-size: 28px; 
 color: #d00; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 font-family: helvetica,arial;   

 
 cursor: pointer;

 
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;

 outline: 1px solid black;
 width: 28px;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 0px;

 position: absolute; 
 
} 

.cross-symbol  {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
  right:0px;
  background:green;
  line-height:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="user">
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="username">some username
            <div class='cross'>
                <span class='cross-symbol'>
                    &times;              
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it still isn't the upper right corner... Changin `vertical-align: bottom` to `top` didn't fix it..

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you are looking for I have changed html and added some css.. i will description if this is correct. thanks

```css
.content  {
 align: center;
 width: 660px;
 background-color: #c2f0c2;
 border: 2px solid black;

 
}

.user  {
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px; 

 background-color: gray;
 margin: 8px;
 border: 1px solid gray;

 display: inline-block;
 
}

.headline {
 background-color: silver;
 border: 1px solid black;

 position: relative;
}

.username  {
 background-color: orange;
}


.cross  { 
/*  font-size: 28px;  */
    color: #d00;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: helvetica,arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    width: 22px;
    height: 20px;
    /* padding: 0px; */
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
 
} 

.cross-symbol  {
 
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: green;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.username{
  position:realtive;
}

.username p{margin:0}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="user">
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="username">
          <p>some username</p>
            <div class='cross'>
                    &times;              
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```